# How to make an array from foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

How to make this array from foreach in my code?

Below is my code

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-24
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-25
        )
)
```

Below is my code but the result is different.

The result is from foreach and I want it to be an array, just like the array above.

```
    foreach ($data['my_undertime'] as $undertime_row) {

        $datetimein = new DateTime($undertime_row->timein);
        $datetimein->format('h:m:s');

        $datetimeout = new DateTime($undertime_row->timeout);
        $datetimeout->format('h:m:s');

        $items = array();

        if ($datetimein->format('h:m:s') > $undertime_row->beg_time && $datetimeout->format('h:m:s') < $undertime_row->end_time) {
            // echo $undertime_row->day;

            $items[]['day'] = $undertime_row->day;
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($items);


    }
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `sql`?

Comment: Because It relates to manipulating data from a database. However I agree that perhaps tagging it as SQL doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($data['my_undertime'] as $undertime_row) {

        $datetimein = new DateTime($undertime_row->timein);
        $datetimein->format('h:m:s');

        $datetimeout = new DateTime($undertime_row->timeout);
        $datetimeout->format('h:m:s');



        if ($datetimein->format('h:m:s') > $undertime_row->beg_time && $datetimeout->format('h:m:s') < $undertime_row->end_time) {
            // echo $undertime_row->day;

            $items[$i]['day'] = $undertime_row->day;
        }
 $i++;



    }
       echo "<pre>";
        print_r($items);
```

try this

Comment: Undertime
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-21
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-22
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2016-11-23
        )

) this is the result sir, its getting close

Comment: not a problem bro, i wasted a lot of time of yours, sorry for that, i didnt checked it earlier about the loop and the array initialization

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line `$items = array();`.

As it is now, `$item` is recreated on each loop. After the `foreach` it ends up remembering only the last iteration of the loop.

If you want to keep all the data in `$item` then move this line of code **before** the `foreach` loop.